# TortoiseHG (Mercurial) - Push branch = abort: push creates new remote head

Tags: mercurial, branching-and-merging, tortoisehg

I closed a public branch inside Tortoise and want to push the change but I get this error:

abort: push creates new remote head 2756e9fac9ea on branch '4.4.72'!

[image: THG Workbench]

Answer (score 1):

1. As you can see on screenshot, you **had** two heads in this branch (see red arrows for local revs 186 + 187). Closing one head of branch you just add one more "closing" changeset 188 (see blue arrow) as descendant of 186, but:

   - not decreased amount of heads
   - not closed branch for Mercurial (in milti-headed branch all heads must have closing commit in order to close branch)
2. If you want *really* **close branch and push it**, you have 2 choices:

   1. Close second head and perform `push -f` - got both heads (== branch 4.4.72) on remote in closed state
   2. Merge heads locally (into one head), close single-head branch and push it in the usual way

[image: Explain]

Comment: Thanks for your answer! After my question I merged the second closed head with the main branch and discarded the changes (if in conflict) made in the 186. I dont want to close the main branch but only the dead closed branch/head.